# How to access objects in my template from Django view?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, chart.js

I need to display attributes of each object exisiting in **data**.How can I access the objects in my template?

**Views.py**

```
data = []
for e in rep:
    data.append({
           'time' : e.time,
           'power' : e.power
            })
return JsonResponse({'data':data},status=200)
```

**template**

```
success : function(response){
            console.log(response)
                  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                      type: 'line',
                      data: {
                          labels: [***here i need to access my objects***],
                          datasets: [{
                              label: "Consumption",
                              data: [{% for e in data %}'{{ e.power }}',{% endfor %}]}})
              }
```

Kind regards.

Comment: the success function showd above,is success function from my ajax call.